# hide traffic source for one page

Tags: php, google-analytics

I use many traffic exchanges to promote my websites. The problem is that on my google analytics stats is mentionated the traffic source. And want to hide this and I wanna know if it is possible in my way.

1. Traffic Website acces my page: www.website.com/page1.php
   (at this moment google analytics will record my source, ok no problem for this page)
2. page1.php will atomaticaly redirect to page2.php BUT I want to know if is possible to hide the page2.php traffic source, and appear like direct visitor, even if the real source is page1.php. It means on page1.php shoud be some php scripts or somethig, anyway I wanna know if is it possible.

Comment: you dont have to share your google ananytics stats

Comment: Use a php filter to set campaign source to direct if request uri euqals page2.php. I think this is the closest you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a robots.txt file. This gives directions to search engines to not view/crawl certain pages of your site. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en

That or just removing the tracking code from that pages you wish to have excluded.